# Cookie seems not to work

Tags: javascript, cookies, js-cookie

Since i needed to have some variables of my programs available in all the pages, i decided to use cookies ([js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)).

```
if ((Cookies.get('j') == null) || (Cookies.get('j') == 0)) {

    Cookies.set('j', 0);
    var j = parseInt(Cookies.get('j'));
}

    Cookies.set('imuno');
    var imuno = Cookies.get('imuno');
    Cookies.set('imdue');
    var imdue = Cookies.get('imdue');
```

Then i wrote two functions:

```
 function check1(){
    if ((src1 == "") || (src1 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Selezionare un'immagine.");
    }
    else {
        controllo();
    }
}
```

and

```
function check2(){
    if ((src2 == "") || (src2 == "undefined")) {
        alert("Selezionare un'immagine.");
    }
    else {
        controllo();
    }
}
```

As you can see, they're two check functions that retrieve another function (`controllo()`) which works like that:

```
function controllo() {

     if (j == 0) {
        alert(j);
        imuno = src1;
        Cookies.set('imuno', src1);
        alert(imuno);
        location.href = "schienale.html";
        j++;
        Cookies.set('j', 1);


    }
    else if (j == 1){
        alert(j);
        imdue = src2;
        Cookies.set('imdue', src2);
        alert(imuno,imdue);
        location.href = "riep.html";
        j++;
        Cookies.set('j', 2);
    }}
```

All this code is written in my external .JS file. Now the funcion `check1()` works perfectly, but when the `check2()` start running the program doesn't work anymore, as if the cookie `j` doesn't mantain its value. How can i solve? Thanks all!

Comment: Maybe you should consider using localStorage instead of Cookie.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier? Because i've never worked with local storage in javascript.

Comment: It is quite simple: var j= localStorage["j"];
 localStorage["j"] = j; You can use localStorage object just like any other object.

Comment: And then where is the data going to be stored?

Comment: It will be stored in your browser local data storage. It is not only easy to use, but it also has some advantages over cookies: like it is never send to server with request, it can store bigger data and some more. It is a HTML5 feature.

Comment: You can also consider of using sessionStorage - usage is same, but data will be wiped with session. (localStorage data will live until you clear it, just like cookie).

Comment: I just need it to save two ot three var, not more. But i'm going to try it, even because i'm still stuck with the program..

Comment: Yes, need that variables empty every time the program start

Comment: If you still have problems - please share your problem in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You mean with the local storage?

Comment: with any implementation of your problem

Comment: Did i miss something in my question or do you just want more information?

Comment: I don't understand where do you set values to src* : it seems that your only difference between check1() and check2() is "if" clause. so if you say that check1() works perfectly - than it is something in src2 I guess.

Comment: Also "j" is not best name for variable - for example : if you have clause like for(var j=0; j<4; j++) - j wont be the same anymore. Such manipulations with j can be silently preformed in external libraries

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nbwmpwag/ Here is where src2 is set (it's the same as src1, just the var name changes)